# Azure VM inbound rules not working

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I have a Windows VM that has been running successfully in Azure for a while, and I opened up several ports and had them all working.  However, I can't hit any of the urls in an external browser right now.

I've confirmed the following:

- can hit the urls in the browser when I RDP into the VM
- have created inbound rules via wf.msc
- have created inbound rules via the network security group in Azure
- have rebooted the VM

What other options do I have to investigate why the ports are not open?

Comment: which ports you had open, can you telnet the public IP and ports out of azure?

Comment: The ports I'm looking at are 85, 8098, 8099.  How do you Telnet out of azure (excuse my ignorance)?  (One of the IPs, our code review tool is http://40.68.115.46:85/)

Comment: azure VM public IP is 40.68.115.46?

Comment: Yep. I'll delete it from the comments once I've resolved the issue. (If I can)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had test in my PC, and the ports are open, please confirm it.
[image]

Comment: @savage The port 85 is open, when hit ip:85, get this error HTTP Error 404,

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how I missed the fact that the urls were only timing out on a specific network.